# Plot pie chart and table of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have to plot pie-chart and a table side by side using matplotlib.

For drawing the pie-chart, I use the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1.EventLogs.value_counts(sort=False).plot.pie()
plt.show()
```

For drawing a table, I use the below code:

```
%%chart table --fields MachineName --data df_result2
```

df_result2 is a table with the list of MachineName's in it.

Not sure whether we can place both pie chart and table side by side. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Look at the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

# sample data
raw_data = {'officer_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'jan_arrests': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'feb_arrests': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
        'march_arrests': [5, 43, 23, 23, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['officer_name', 'jan_arrests', 'feb_arrests', 'march_arrests'])
df['total_arrests'] = df['jan_arrests'] + df['feb_arrests'] + df['march_arrests']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
# plot chart
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
df.plot(kind='pie', y = 'total_arrests', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
 startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df['officer_name'], legend = False, fontsize=14)

# plot table
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
plt.axis('off')
tbl = table(ax2, df, loc='center')
tbl.auto_set_font_size(False)
tbl.set_fontsize(14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how to save it as jpg?

Comment: Hi All, fyi
You need to change a package 'pandas.tools.plotting' to 'pandas.plotting' in order to run

Comment: Is there a way to add distance between `total_arrests` and `Molly` in the plot such that they do not overlap? Or perhaps relocate `total_arrests` at the bottom of the pie chart?

Comment: Can i show actual counts instead of percentage inside the pie chart?

Comment: `plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')`
why exactly 121

Answer (score 41):

A very simple solution
`df.whatever.value_counts().plot(kind='pie')`

Comment: OP was asking for a different thing. They already know how to plot pie charts. See the 2nd line of the code in the question, it's the same as what you wrote.

Comment: Is there a way to remove small elements and just label them as "other"?

Comment: how to add percentage text?

Comment: @SharkDeng try this to add this param -> autopct='%1.1f%%' (single precision)