# How do I plot a pie chart with this give dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have this dataframe and I wanted to plot a pandas pie chart out of it. However I have tried but to no avail. Below is the code that I have used to try attempting.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import the csv file
dataname = 'Datasets\\tax-and-penalty-arising-from-audits-by-tax-type.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(dataname)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# drop the no_of_cases column since we will not be using it
df2 = df.drop(['tax_and_penalty_arising'],axis=1)

# merge the values: individual income tax and corporate income tax together under tax type together as they can be seen to be seperated in some years eg 2011
dictionary = {'Corporate Income Tax':'Individual and Corporate Income Tax','Individual Income Tax':'Individual and Corporate Income Tax'}
df3 = df2.groupby(['financial_year',df2['tax_type'].replace(dictionary)]).sum().reset_index()

# get only the data from the latest financial_year(2018)
df4 = df3[(df3.financial_year == (2018))].reset_index(drop=True)

# drop the column financial_year as we will not be using it
df4 = df4.drop(['financial_year'],axis=1)

#  print the dataframe   
# print(df4)
df4

# plot out the pie chart
ax = df4.plot.pie(y='no_of_cases',figsize=(10,10))
ax.legend(labels='tax_type')
plt.pie(df4['no_of_cases'],labels=df['tax_type'],shadow=False,startangle=90)
plt.show()
```

This is the dataframe that I've gotten:

[image: Image Here]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337918/plot-pie-chart-and-table-of-pandas-dataframe

Comment: this https://kanoki.org/2019/09/16/dataframe-visualization-with-pandas-plot/ documentation may help