# Overlapping legend for pandas plot with a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a pie chart with pandas plot function, with the following code and matplotlib:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
# plot chart
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
dfhelp.plot(kind='pie', y = 'Prozentuale Gesamt', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%',
            startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=dfhelp['Anzahl Geschäfte in der Gruppe'], legend = False, fontsize=14)
plt.show
```

the output looks like:

[image]

the problem is, the percentages and legend are overlapping, do you have any idea to fix that? For the plotting I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337918/plot-pie-chart-and-table-of-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: There's a [good sample](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html) from the docs.

Comment: It's happening because you have a lot of small wedges. You can probably follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578860/6267086) to work around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easier and more readable version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577505/how-to-avoid-overlapping-of-labels-autopct-in-a-matplotlib-pie-chart/23578860#23578860) in my opinion (but credits to that answer for making it possible).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['Tesla', 'GM', 'Ford', 'Nissan', 'Other'], 
     'col2': [117, 95, 54, 10, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

# Calculate percentages points
percent = 100.*df.col2/df.col2.sum()

# Write label in the format "Manufacturer - Percentage %"
labels = ['{0} - {1:1.2f} %'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(df.col1, percent)]

ax = df.col2.plot(kind='pie', labels=None) # the pie plot
ax.axis('equal') # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(False) # disable y-axis label
# add the legend
ax.legend(labels, loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, 1.), fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

[image]