# I would like to plot a pie chart from my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I would like to plot a pie chart from my pandas data Frame of customer buying behaviours

| PREMIUM_CUSTOMER | TOT_SALES |
| --- | --- |
| Mainstream | 750744.50 |
| Budget | 676211.55 |
| Premium | 507458.95 |

This is my code so far

```py
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
labels = ['Mainstream','Budget','Premium']
df_customer.plt.pie("PREMIUM_CUSTOMER","TOT_SALES",labels=labels,wedgeprops={'edgecolor':'black'}, shadow = True,startangle =90, autopct='%1.11f%%')
plt.title("Percentage of sales to customer types ")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337918/plot-pie-chart-and-table-of-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Maybe add an `'o'` in `df_customer.plot.pie`? Maybe you want to remove `labels=` as they come from a dataframe column? What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @JohnanC the pie chart is not showing

Comment: What error or warning do you get?  Did you try `df_customer.set_index("PREMIUM_CUSTOMER")["TOT_SALES"].plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%')`?